# How to change the value of a key in a dictionary which is in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I change the value of the key `"current_date"`. I've tried it with `months[month].update({current_date: int(minute)})`, but that only gave me a new dictionary and didn't change my old one. So how can I add time, for example 60 min?

```
Current Dictionary
months = {"January":{"current_date": 60}}

Update Dictionary
months = {"January":{"current_date": 120}}
```

I'm sorry if this question already got asked, but I simply wasn't able to find a solution...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope it is what you're looking for:

```
months = {"January":{"current_date": 60}} #initializing
months["January"]["current_date"] = 120 #updating
```

To add 60 mins:

```
months = {"January":{"current_date": 60}}
months["January"]["current_date"] = months["January"]["current_date"] + 60
```

Or more efficient:

```
months = {"January":{"current_date": 60}}
months["January"]["current_date"] += 60
```

Comment: I'd prefer `months["January"]["current_date"] += 60`

Comment: yes but using my way he also sees how to get the value

Comment: right, but in-place add is more efficient so it doesn't look up 4 keys in the dicts, only 2.

Comment: @T.Wimma Wow, I wasn't expecting that it would be so easy. Thank you! You just saved 4 hours of work. <3

Comment: hey it was a simple one, but answer is very complete so well done